# Hyperelliptic curve with prescribed rational points?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Given a set of rational points $S$, does there always exist a hyperelliptic curve $C$ such that $C(\mathbb{Q})=S$?

Namely, which sets could arise as the set of rational points of a hyperelliptic curve? Do we have any restrictions or conjectures? Are there any sets that we know cannot be the set of rational points of a hyperelliptic curve (excluding obvious ones, like those containing $(x,y)$ but not $(x,-y)$)?

Comment: Funny question! :) E.g., are there cases where the obvious Lagrange interpolation does not allow any _further_ rational points? :)

Comment: Given any set of $x,y$ values stable under $(x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$, a generic polynomial of large even degree such that $f(x) = y^2$ for these values should have no other rational points. This follows from the general philosophy that hyperelliptic curves should have as few points as possible. I don't know if it follows from any named conjecture. I don't think it could possibly be in reach of current technology.

Comment: It's fairly clear what you're asking, but keep in mind that a hyperelliptic curve is not the same thing as an equation $y^2=f(x)$. The former is an abstract object that admits many different embeddings into projective spaces of many different dimensions. And when you talk about $S$ being a "set of rational points", you could mean in any one of a number of different spaces. Finally, I think that you probably want to specify that $C$ is defined over $\mathbb Q$, i.e., that $f(x)\in\mathbb Q[x]$. Otherwise one might be able to cheat using an $f(x)$ having irrational coefficients.